# Why doesn't the query object run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm a beginner at node.js and express.js and I'm practicing on http verb.
So when I want to work with "req.query" in a post or a get method, it's like the code doesn't run.
Can you tell me why?

I searched on how to use it but I've only found about bodyparser module and query string.
On codecademy.com, there was an exercise on http verb where I used req.query in a post method. I am doing almost the same thing but it doesn't work.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var dataFile = require("./dataFile.js");

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
   res.send("welcome to our website");
});

app.get("/animes", (req, res)=>{
   res.send(dataFile.animes);
});

app.get("/animes/:name", (req, res)=>{
   res.send(dataFile.animes[req.params.name]);
 });
 app.get("/animes/addget",(req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.query);
 });
 app.post("/animes/addpost",(req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
 });


 var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, (req, res)=>{
   console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
//Here is the dataFile.js where there is the animes object
animes = [
{name: "naruto", status: "ongoing", episodes: "720+"},
{name:"onepiece", status: "ongoing", episodes: "870+"}
];
module.exports.animes = animes;
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong. And also which is better to use in this case: GET or POST Method.
Thank you in advance
N.B: I modified it a little bit but I have the same problem. I can't get my query object.

Comment: Try to add a `/` before your route `app.get("/animes/add",(req, res)=>{`.
about if its better to use GET or POST, it depends, if you are retriving data it is best to use GET.

Comment: maybe you're missing some initialization, why don't you paste the whole code snippet?

Comment: It is an additional answer for @jezer-chilel 's post, it should be `app.post("/animes/add"` and `app.get("/animes/add"`. And you have to be sure that you have created a server on your local machine `app.listen(3090)` and last you should use bodyParser because you are making post request.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem. It was the route with a parameter that blocked the route with queries from running. But I don't know why, so if anyone can help, i would appreciate it.